# PivotItem Height

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I hope someone can help me with a PivotControl issue. In my app there's a Pivot that binds to a source with three items which can change. To problem is that each item has different info so I end up with three Pivot Items with different height (for an exmaple - item1 - 100, i2 - 300 and i3 - 200).

At least my expactations was that on each screen the Pivot will take as much place as the current item needs. Still the pivot's height is set to the highest item. At the end this behaviour does make sense, yet I need to shrink it to the current item's height. Any ideas ?

Comment: Perhaps you could show us some XAML to show what you're putting in your `Pivot`; it might help to give you an answer. If you add a `ScrollViewer` as the first child item in each `PivotItem` and add your item contents to that, it should maintain a consistent height across items and scroll those that are too big.

Comment: Why would you need to shrink it?  What else would you be displaying on the page that would make that worth doing?

Comment: It would be easier to show you as I don't have access to the code right now. So this is basically a woman period tracker app called Woman Calendar. The calendar itself holds different months as you can see on the first screenshot. http://social.zune.net/redirect?type=phoneApp&id=1475828d-8d46-e011-854c-00237de2db9e   Also this image makes it clear why I need a pivot which is not full height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pivot control is intented to take up the whole page/screen. It is not designed to be used with other UI elements above or below it.

The control does not support the effect you are trying to achieve.

In terms of creating an application which works the way the user expects/like other apps on the phone, you may wish to reconsider the way you're structuring your page and designing your UI.

**Update**
If you want to get this effect, just put everything inside the PivotItem. If you put the same thing in multiple items, be sure to cache it and avoid duplication in the model.

Comment: Check the first screenshot to see why I need this http://social.zune.net/redirect?type=phoneApp&id=1475828d-8d46-e011-854c-00237de2db9e

Comment: @Miroslav that shows what you're trying to do, not why you need it.

Comment: Fair enough. I thought that this is the best way for the users to use the calendar. They click on a day and the summary below gets populated with the relevant data. I don't think popups would be better.

Comment: @Miroslav that's not the behaviour of the built in calendar. Also, from the screenshot it wasn't clear that the data being displayed was related to a particular date, or that there was a date which had been selected. How did your users find this when you did usability testing? That aside, putting it all in the pivotitem should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I guess as you suggested I should go back to the old version, where everything was inside the pivot.